# Removing fields from flyout in CRM 2015 OOB entity

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am customizing the contact entity (OOB) in CRM 2015. One of the attributes of this entity is Address, which is a composite attribute built using the following

1. Street1
2. **City**
3. State/Province

I like to remove the **City** field from the flyout alltogether.

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

> Even though, currently there is no supported way to do control this (hopefully Microsoft might make this available in future release) But a little tweak did the trick for me to overcome this challenge.

I created a Business Rule ho hide the default fields (City, State and Country) from the form. I specifically wrote the Business Rule without specifying any conditions which means it will load/work all the time.

[image]

Consequently, with the effect of Business Rule the fields got hidden from the flyout menu as well. I changed the Display name of Address Composite Field to Street and made it Visible, also included the rest 3 new Lookup under same section.

Finally my requirement got fulfilled now as I was able to use the composite field to capture the 4-fields (Street1, Street2, Street3 and Zip Code) and also use the individual lookups for the City, State and Country.

Link: https://ashwaniashwin.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/update-change-address-composite-field-in-crm-2013-with-busoness-rules/